# How to start a new activity

Tags: android, methods, call, new-operator

I have tried the method in the code below to start a new activity. Everything shows good but on emulator it doesn't run properly. What am I doing wrong?

Method on MainActivity starting the new activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button1;

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activi,main); 
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        button1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intent); 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i have 3 activityxml+3mainactivity and with two buttons each for one activity i want to open newtextview

Comment: You need to click `button1` to go to `MainActivity2`. Can you show the error that is shown when you click `button1`

Comment: Please paste your code as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined upward navigation? Each screen which is not the main entry point must provide a navigation logic to its parent.

in `AndroidManifest.xml`, under the `<activity>` tag for `MainActivity2`:

```xml
<activity android:name=".MainActivity2"
          android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
```